# Python BaseHash accepts only integer

Tags: python, encryption, hash, passwords

Im trying to hash a password using python's `BaseHash` as following:

```
import basehash

hash_fn = basehash.base36() 
hash_value = hash_fn.hash("1") # returns 'M8YZRZ'
unhashed = hash_fn.unhash('M8YZRZ') # returns 1
```

when im trying to hash a strings such:

```
hash_value = hash_fn.hash("hellooo")
```

i get  `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hellooo'`. To mention, i have search this error almost everywhere but cant find the solution.
Whats wrong with this?

Comment: It's not a hash and wasn't built for this case: *BaseHash is a small library for creating reversible obfuscated **identifier** hashes to a given base and length.* (emphasis mine). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That library just takes numbers up to a certain size. This is described directly on the home page. So it is clear what is wrong, but not clear what you're trying to do. You may need to read a tutorial on password hashing. bcrypt or a form of Argon2 makes more sense.